# How to Insert Data into Tempdb Until Amount of Distinct Values Met

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a main table named **`tblorder`**.
It contains `CUID`(Customer ID), `CuName`(Customer Name) and `OrDate`(Order Date) that I care about.
It is currently ordered by `date` in ascending order(ex. 2001 before 2002).

**Objective:**
Trying to retrieve most recent 1 Million DISTINCT Customer's `CUID` and `CuName`S, and  `Insert` them Into a `Tempdb`(#Recent1M) for Later Joining Uses.

**So I:**

1. Would Need Order By `desc` to flip the date to retrieve most recent 1 Million Customers
2. Only want first 1 Million DISTINCT Customer Information(`CUID`, `CuName`)

I know following code is not correct, but it is the main idea. I just can't figure out the correct syntax. So far I have the `While` Loop with `Select` `Into` as the most plausible solution.

**SQL Platform:** SSMS

```
Declare @DC integer
Set @DC = Count(distinct(CUID)) from #Recent1M))
While (@DC <1000000)
Begin
Select CuID,CuName into #Recent1MCus from tblorder
End
```

Thank you very much, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just do this?

```
select distinct top 1000000 cuid, cuname
into #Recent1MCus
from tblorder;
```

If the names might not be distinct, you can do:

```
select top 1000000 cuid, cuname
into #Recent1MCus
from (select o.*, row_number() over (partition by cuid order by ordate desc) as seqnum
      from tblorder o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: you want to order by `OrDate DESC` not by `cuid` both in your partition and in your main select. to get the most recent.

Comment: So change the cuid to ordate?

Comment: Also, is while loop/case when doable for this case?

Comment: @stillthrough . . . You want to avoid loops if a set-based query yields the same results.

Comment: @stillthrough Is a loop doable for this, yes, is it a good idea, no. Looping is a more expensive procedure than the alternative.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You have to apply the order to the select statement, not just the partition of the windowing, since they want only the newest million customers, the order in the window will get you the newest per customer, but does not guarantee the newest customers.

Answer (score 1):

TOP 1000000 is the way to go, but you're going to need an ORDER BY clause or you will get arbitrary results.  In your case, you mentioned that you wanted the most recent ones, so:

```
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
```

Also, you might consider using GROUP BY rather than DISTINCT.  I think it looks cleaner and keeps the select list a select list so you have the option to include whatever else you might want (as I took the liberty of doing).  Notice that, because of the grouping, the ORDER BY now uses MAX(ordate) since customers can presumably have multiple ordate's and we are interested in the most recent. So:

```
select top 1000000 cuid, cuname, sum(order_value) as ca_ching, count(distinct(order_id)) as order_count
into #Recent1MCus
from tblorder
group by cuid, cuname
order by max(ordate) desc
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This order by happens after group by. I want the order by desc happen first then select the top 1m to get the most recent. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I think this is what you want: at it's heart, unique cuid, cuname combos, ordered by the recent actity.  The location of the ORDER BY clause has to do with SQL syntax.  It is ordering the results of the SELECT statement (beginning on the first line) that it is part of.

Comment: Your comment did make me notice that I had forgotten type 'max(ordate)' when I first posted this, so thanks.

Comment: I think this better answers the question.

Comment: Nice of you to say, @Gordon.  Thanks a bunch.  This is at least the third time we've run into each other today.  We were the only two on the sum-duplicate-book-purchases-by-employee post too (including the guy who posted the question who seems to have disappeared).

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY <colname> DESC` to get latest unique records.
 Try this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT top 1000000 
    cuid, 
    cuname
INTO #Recent1MCus
FROM tblorder
ORDER BY OrDate DESC;
```